# How to add popup question before sending the dropzone files?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, dropzone

I'm using dropzone for multiple file uploading. When a file drag n drop I want to added a popup ask a question from specific file extensions and then pass that paramaeter. currently even though popup appeared file is uploading before that so ' formData.append("convert", $('#convertFile').val());' this value will not come correctly. please advice?

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
     new Dropzone(document.body, {
        url: "/upload/",
        parallelUploads: 1,
        clickable: "#fileUpload",
         init: function () {
             var drop = this;
             this.on('error', function (file, errorMessage) {

             });
         },
         accept: function(file, done) {
             var ext = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
             if ($.inArray(ext, ['mov', 'wmv']) !== -1) {
                 swal({
                     title: 'Convert ',
                     html: "Do you want to convert this media ?" +
                     "<br>" +
                     '<button type="button" role="button" tabindex="0" id="convertUpload">' + 'Convert' + '</button>' +
                     '<button type="button" role="button" tabindex="0"  id="rawUpload">' + 'Do not convert' + '</button>',

                 }).catch(swal.noop);
                 $(document).on('click', '#convertUpload', function() {
                     $('#sidebar #upload #convertFile').val(1);
                     swal.clickConfirm();
                 });

                 $(document).on('click', '#rawUpload', function() {
                     $('#sidebar #upload #convertFile').val(0);
                     swal.clickConfirm();

                 });
             }
             done();
         },
         sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
             formData.append("convert", $('#convertFile').val());
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

After you determine (from user input) whether or not the file should be converted, you can add a property directly to the file object.

`file.convertFile = 1;` or `file.convertFile = 0;`

Later in your code, you can easily access it any other time you're working with that object. You wont have to pass the value as a function param, it will be saved to the it's owner, the file object!

**Example:**

```
<style>
    #fileUpload {
        margin: 20px; 
        height: 200px; 
        width: 200px; 
        border: 2px dotted green; 
    }
</style>

<div id="fileUpload"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.dropzonejs.com/js/dropzone.js"></script>

<script>
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    const dropzone_fileUpload = new Dropzone('#fileUpload', {
        url: "/upload/",
        parallelUploads: 1,
        accept: function(file, done){
            const extension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            const can_be_converted = ['mov','wmv','html','jpg'].includes(extension); // returns true if array "includes" extension

            if (can_be_converted) {
                const userAgreesToConvert = confirm('Would you like to convert this .'+ extension +' file?'); // return true if they accept
                file.convertFile = userAgreesToConvert ? 1 : 0; // add property to file object
            }

            done(); 
        },
        sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
            // here, we have access to the file and it's new property, "convertFile"
            if (file.convertFile !== undefined){
                console.log(`${file.convertFile ? 'CONVERT FILE:' : 'DO NOT CONVERT FILE:'} ${file.name}`); 
            } else {
                console.log(`Dont care about ${file.name}`);
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

[**DEMO (JS Fiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/5zL7etd1/4/)

Note: I added extra extension types to test with, I don't have `wmv` files quickly accessible. Also, I removed most the the unnecessary code to the keep the answer for concise and specific. I didn't use `swal()` either, because I didn't want to download their library, I couldn't find their CDN, and it's not relevant to the issue anyway.

Please review the example and try your best to apply the techniques here to your own code. This is likely not a copy & paste solution, but I promise you will learn more if you struggle just a tiny bit to get it to work.

**Good luck**!!

Comment: thanks for the solution, when I check it works with your solution. but when I did the same for sweetalert confimration it didn't work. What I see is when the alert box come it calls send  even befroe I click confirm or cancel